# KML file - Is there a way to completely disable description bubbles?

Tags: kml, infowindow

I have a rather simple .kml file to display a polygon on a Google Map. By default, the polygon causes the cursor to switch to a hand/pointer, and when clicked, displays an empty description bubble.

I have no description, therefore the white bubble (infowindow) is empty.

And what I want is NO bubble at all. I'd love for the hand/pointer cursor to go away as well.

I've found nothing on the web that answers this question.

Thanks!

---

I have added my code to my original question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>RMAhidden.kml</name>
    <Style id="poly-000000-1-76-nodesc-normal0">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>004b8800</color>
            <width>0</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>99359ca3</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="poly-000000-1-76-nodesc-highlight0">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>004b8800</color>
            <width>0</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>99359ca3</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="poly-000000-1-76-nodesc1">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#poly-000000-1-76-nodesc-normal0</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#poly-000000-1-76-nodesc-highlight0</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Placemark>
        <styleUrl>#poly-000000-1-76-nodesc1</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                    <coordinates>
                        -104.7937775,39.87088139999999,0 -104.8653603,39.87061789999999,0 -104.8996925,39.8413634,0 -104.8979759,39.8397817,0 -104.8978043,39.836091,0 -104.8978043,39.83371830000001,0 -104.8996925,39.8317409,0 -104.9022675,39.830159,0 -104.9034691,39.8268633,0 -104.9031258,39.8127557,0 -104.9010658,39.8126238,0 -104.9000359,39.8113052,0 -104.8981476,39.8087998,0 -104.895401,39.8074811,0 -104.8916245,39.80734919999999,0 -104.8845863,39.8070855,0 -104.884511,39.812922,0 -104.8667336,39.8131513,0 -104.8667336,39.7985133,0 -104.8478508,39.7986452,0 -104.8478508,39.8004916,0 -104.8435593,39.8004916,0 -104.8437309,39.7982495,0 -104.7917175,39.7979858,0 -104.7910309,39.8611313,0 -104.7912025,39.8661383,0 -104.7937775,39.87088139999999,0 
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
        <description></description>
        <ExtendedData>
            <Data name="Id">
            </Data>
            <Data name="T_NAME">
            </Data>
            <Data name="T_STATUS">
            </Data>
            <Data name="T_R_LENGTH">
            </Data>
            <Data name="T_SOURCE">
            </Data>
            <Data name="T_BIKE">
            </Data>
            <Data name="FEAT_RAST">
            </Data>
            <Data name="Section">
            </Data>
            <Data name="Sect_Name">
            </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: How are you displaying the KML on Google Maps?  What does that code look like?  What does your KML look like?  When you say you have "no description", are the tags empty or not there?

Comment: Use the snippet command within the KML to disable the bubble. `<Snippet maxLines="0" >` https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference?hl=en

Comment: How are you displaying the KML?  Your original KML doesn't display an infowindow on a [KmlLayer on the Google Maps Javascript API v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20150914_desc.kml)

Answer (score 0):

To disable the popup balloon you can add a [BalloonStyle](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#balloonstyle) with displayMode=hide to your Style.

If `<displayMode>` is hide, Google Earth does not display the balloon.

```
<Style id="poly-000000-1-76-nodesc-normal0">
    <BalloonStyle>
        <displayMode>hide</displayMode>     <!-- default or hide -->
    </BalloonStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>004b8800</color>
        <width>0</width>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>99359ca3</color>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
```

Note that `<BalloonStyle>` and `<displayMode>` elements may not be supported in all JavaScript libraries if that is how you are rendering the KML

Comment: Hmmm. Tried it. Didn't work.

My map must fall into the "not supported" in my JavaScript library bucket.

Thanks JasonM1.